# Scala synchronized collections

Tags: java, scala, collections, concurrency

I am looking for a concise and straightforward way to use synchronized/concurrent sets/lists in Scala. The traits [`SynchronizedSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedSet.html),... are deprecated, and the standard library, the package [`scala.collection.concurrent`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/index.html) only provides concurrent maps.

Although one could easily implement "proxy collections" using concurrent maps internally, this does not feel "Scala-ish". The synchronized collections from Java, obtained via `Collections.synchronizedSet()` are no alternative, as only their simple methods are synchronized (see Javadoc).

Am I missing something?

Comment: scaladoc recommends `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[A,Unit]`.

Comment: yes, that is an implementation (via scala conversion) of the trait [`concurrent.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.html) (see <http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#concurrent_maps>). I might have to live with using maps and ignoring the values...